# How to keep some files from old hard disk (which currently has Windows 8.1 and will be formatted) after clean-installing Windows 8.1 in SSD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, installation, ssd, windows-8.1

I have a hard disk which currently has Windows 8.1.
I've ordered a new SSD hard disk and I want to (clean)install Windows 8.1 x64 in it.
The old hard disk will be formatted - **I just want to keep about 160 GB of data from it.

The problem is that I don't have a (third) external hard disk to simply copy the files in it.**

---

What I've thought to do is to create an extra partition in the old hard disk
and move the 160GB of data in it
(then, at the end I'll format the other partition -the one containing Windows- and then I'll merge the two).

[From what I've read](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-8-1-on-ssd/):

> If you have connected two or more Hard Disk Drives or SSD,
>   if possible, we suggest you disconnect all other drives
>   except the one that you would like to use for Windows 8.1 install.
>   That is, for instance, if you have connected one SSD and another HD Drive,
>   we recommend you disconnect the hard drive to avid Windows from creating any partition on that drive.

Therefore, I'll have to disconnect the old hard disk while installing Windows in the SSD.

After the installation, when I'll reconnect the old hard disk, it will unfortunately also be bootable.
Can this be avoided?
In other words, before disconnecting that hard disk,
is it possible to delete it's bootloader from inside Windows,
so that, when I reconnect the old hard disk (i.e. after I (clean)install Windows in the SSD)
it will not be bootable anymore?

Or, is there an easier way to keep my old data?

Comment: Hi Kostas. How large will the new SSD be? Can you spare the space on that one to copy your files while reformatting the HDD? And more generally, must you reformat? (Is there some particular reason why you don't want to just delete the files you don't want to keep, and perhaps run a free space wipe afterwards?) The Windows MBR/GPT boot loader code would still be there (and I think it'd be even if you reformat), but the disk won't be bootable because no other components of the OS are available on it. Disconnecting any other drives while you format a new drive is a sensible precaution.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it will be bootable. Your extra partition scenario sounds good.

Comment: Michael Kjörling: It will be 250GB. You mean: to also connect the SSD, move the files to it, disconnect the old one, and then run Windows setup to do the install in an non-empty SSD? Yes, I have to reformat, because I have installed a lot of programs in my current one, and this inevitably must have slowed down the system a bit.  
 
gronostaj: Yes, I think I'll follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can plug in both drives at the same time:

```
Unplug the old drive. Plug in the new drive. Install Windows 8. Plug in the old drive
once installation is complete. Transfer files.
```

As for the old one being bootable after you've made your new drive, it shouldn't be an issue. Your machine will most likely boot from the last booted device which would be your newly formatted SSD, otherwise it will ask you which drive you want to boot from, select one, if it's wrong, reboot and select the other one. Now you can transfer files and format your old drive.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but unfortunately my SSD proved faulty soon after I bought it and I had to RMA it.
A few days ago I got the replacement.

The point is that unfortunately my question was based on a misunderstanding:
I thought, that if both the SSD and the HD were bootable, then some kind of conflict would occur during boot, and the system wouldn't stary.

But that was not the case:
when I installed the replacement SSD,
I forgot to disconnect the older one.
But it proved that didnt matter,
because windows manages the multi boot options great,
so, during boot I was able to choose to choose from which of the disks to boot:
[image]

So, I can boot with either the SSD or the old hard disk without a problem,
in other words, the old drive remained bootable after installing windows to the SSD.
and there was no extra partition created in the SSD:
[image]

Anyway, thank you for the replies, and sorry for my misconception.